# Generate barcode using Zxing in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, zxing.net

I am trying to display a barcode in my app using binding in my xaml. My question  is how can I convert the barcode to be used in the xaml Image source. I have tried using a byte property but I get this compile error : **"Cannot implicitly convert Zxing barcode image view to 'byte'"**. Any guidance on how to achieve this will be appreciate, thanks.

**Cards.cs**

```
 public class Cards
    {
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public int DiscountLevelID { get; set; }
        public string DiscountLevel { get; set; }
        public double DiscountLevelAmount { get; set; }
        public bool StoreCustomerGiftCard { get; set; }
        public bool StoreCustomerLoyalty { get; set; }
        public int LoyaltyLevelID { get; set; }
        public string LoyaltyLevel { get; set; }
        public double LoyaltyLevelRatio { get; set; }
        public double Balance { get; set; }
        public int StoreNumber { get; set; }
        public string CardNumber { get; set; }
        public bool IsError { get; set; }
        public object ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string CustomerLogo { get; set; }
        public byte BarCode { get; set; }

    }
```

**Cards.xaml.cs**

```
ZXingBarcodeImageView barcode;

 barcode = new ZXingBarcodeImageView { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand };
                        barcode.BarcodeFormat = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
                        barcode.BarcodeOptions.Width = 300;
                        barcode.BarcodeOptions.Height = 300;
                        barcode.BarcodeOptions.Margin = 10;
                        barcode.BarcodeValue = i.CardNumber;

                        i.BarCode = barcode;
```

**Cards.xaml**

```
<Image Source="{Binding BarCode}" />
```

Answer (score 4):

`ZXingBarcodeImageView` inherits directly from `Image`, so you use it as an alternative to `Image`, not as a source for `Image`

```
xmlns:zx="clr-namespace:ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms;assembly=ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms"
xmlns:zxcm="clr-namespace:ZXing.Common;assembly=zxing.portable"

<zx:ZXingBarcodeImageView
    BarcodeFormat="QR_CODE"
    BarcodeValue="{Binding CardNumber}"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <zx:ZXingBarcodeImageView.BarcodeOptions>
      <zxcm:EncodingOptions Width="300" Height="300" />
    </zx:ZXingBarcodeImageView.BarcodeOptions>
</zx:ZXingBarcodeImageView>
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried what you said and the barcode still isn't displaying :(

Comment: Im getting the following exception : System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: I added this to my MainActivity.cs, global::ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init(); . Any idea why it's not working

Comment: you need to look at the InnerException to get the root cause

Comment: @JanineAlexander is it fixed? I also have similar problem